# PDO SQL Query Select

Tags: php, mysql

I have write a SQL query with PDO and I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

My code is:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;charset=utf8;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT
            '".$perfix."'_k2_items.id AS `ItemId`,
            '".$perfix."'_k2_items.title AS `Title`,
            '".$perfix."'_k2_items.alias AS `Alias`,
            '".$perfix."'_k2_items.catid AS `CatId`,
            LEFT('".$perfix."'_k2_items.introtext,1000) AS `Fulltext`,
            '".$perfix."'_k2_items.created AS `created`,
            '".$perfix."'_k2_categories.name AS `CatName`
            FROM '".$perfix."'_k2_items
            INNER JOIN '".$perfix."'_k2_categories 
            ON '".$perfix."'_k2_items.catid = '".$perfix."'_k2_categories.id  
            WHERE '".$perfix."'_k2_items.featured = '1' ";
```

The error is the prefix. I think that I have made a sytax error.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: What's the value of `$perfix`? Why do you have it enclosed in quotation marks (')?

Comment: The pefix is an sting. Is the perfix of the sql table. Is this one: $perfix="table1"; The quotation marks (') are because I have use the duble quotation in the beginning of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remove `'` from `'".$perfix."'`.

Try

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;charset=utf8;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT
            ".$perfix."_k2_items.id AS `ItemId`,
            ".$perfix."_k2_items.title AS `Title`,
            ".$perfix."_k2_items.alias AS `Alias`,
            ".$perfix."_k2_items.catid AS `CatId`,
            LEFT(".$perfix."_k2_items.introtext,1000) AS `Fulltext`,
            ".$perfix."_k2_items.created AS `created`,
            ".$perfix."_k2_categories.name AS `CatName`
            FROM ".$perfix."_k2_items
            INNER JOIN ".$perfix."_k2_categories 
            ON ".$perfix."_k2_items.catid = ".$perfix."_k2_categories.id  
            WHERE ".$perfix."_k2_items.featured = '1' ";
```

Comment: @JamesFourikis I'm glad it works for you. Please accept my answer if you feel it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes is not something that belongs to every variable added to the query. Single quotes has very special meaning in SQL and have to be used only when required. For the **part of table name** they are not.

Also, learn to use table aliases, to make your SQL less littered.

```
$sql = "SELECT i.id, i.title, i.alias, i.catid, i.created,
        LEFT(i.introtext,1000) fulltext,
        c.name category
        FROM {$perfix}_k2_items i
        INNER JOIN {$perfix}_k2_categories c
        ON i.catid = c.id  
        WHERE i.featured = '1'";
```

Comment: Thank you. I try to use table aliases!